# How to find out the number of video calls that are currently running on jitsi-meet?

Tags: jitsi-meet

I want to limit the number of video calls that can be initiated at a time due to the resource limits.
How can I find out the number of calls/rooms that are currently ongoing on my jitsi-meet instance?

Once I find this number out, I can prevent further calls if the number exceeds a certain limit.

I tried going through the jitsi-meet documentation but there was nothing I could find related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for Prosody that provides a list of currently running video calls along with other metadata.

Link: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/resources/prosody-plugins/mod_muc_census.lua